# Please create tag `covariate`

Tags: feature-request, tags

I am surprised to see that a `covariate` tag does not yet exist, as it would be more applicable than any of the other tags I had to settle for when posting this question:  [Should covariates that are not statistically significant be 'kept in' when creating a model?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66448/should-covariates-that-are-not-statistically-significant-be-kept-in-when-creat)

Note:  `covariance` exists, but does not seem to be a match at all, as it does not distinguish between IVs that are in or not in a model.

Side note:  I am tagging this as a feature request, since I am asking for a change, but it's a tiny feature request...which could be implemented by any one of many, many site users! ;)

Comment: I feel obliged to point out here that [covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance) is not remotely the same thing as a [covariate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariate). That they are different concepts has nothing to do w/ whether any given IV is or is not in a model.

Comment: @gung I completely agree.  That's exactly why I did not want to use "covariance", the closest tag that appeared when I started to type "covariate".

Answer (score 5):

Currently, we have:

[covariate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariate) (x 23) and [covariance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/covariance) (x 298), both with excerpt and wiki filled in.

It was discussed in comments that these tags have different meanings. If anyone sees the opportunity to improve them, please go ahead.

Comment: They both have tag wiki excerpts that seem perfectly adequate.